# Exit fullscreen breaks in Mountain Lion after changing window's delegate

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-lion, fullscreen

I created my project from the Xcode template for non-document based Cocoa Application.

I have a custom `NSWindowController` that, after being instantiated on startup, takes possession of the default window (defined in `MainMenu.xib`).

If I leave the app delegate's window as it is, I can toggle fullscreen mode with `command-F` (set to `-toggleFullscreen:` in a menu item), or I can exit from fullscreen by pressing `ESC`.

Once I set my window controller as the window's `delegate` (I need this to do some OpenGL adjustments on enter/exit fullscreen, etc.), I can still enter fullscreen by pressing `command+F`, but I can no longer exit fullscreen (save for `command+tab` to another app, or `command+Q`).

Also, the Apple docs mention setting the menu action to `-toggleFullscreen:` **and the target to `nil`**. How is this last part done in Interface Builder? (I connected the action to First Responder's `-toggleFullscreen:`)

What should I do?

Comment: Cocoa desktop can be so complicated sometimes. Every time I want to implement something, I end up with 10 browser windows open into the Developer Library.

Comment: You can answer your own question so that people will know this question is answered.

Comment: There, I moved the edit to a dedicated answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found the problem (posting the question in SO seems to be a condition to finding the solution, always...)

The offending line was not setting the delegate, but what I was doing to the window after entering fullscreen mode. In particular, as soon as I commented out the following line 
 `[window setStyleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask];` in the code below:

```
- (void) windowDidEnterFullScreen:(NSNotification*) notification
{
    NSWindow* window = [self window];

    NSRect mainDisplayRect = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];
    [window setStyleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask];
    [window setContentSize:mainDisplayRect.size];
    [window setLevel:NSMainMenuWindowLevel + 1];
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];

    NSRect windowFrame = [window frame];
    windowFrame.origin.x = 0;
    windowFrame.origin.y = 0;
    [window setFrame:windowFrame display:YES];
}
```

...the expected enter/exit fullscreen mode behaviour was fixed.

Comment: And you know you can also mark it as correct too so it'll show up as green! :)

Comment: +1 for the first sentence :D (and solving the issue of course)